# WPF Ribbon Multiple Comboboxes in same Group

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I have multiple RibbonComboBoxes in one RibbonGroup and I keep having anything but the very first RibbonComboBox not return null on me.  It doesn't seem to be finding any other ComboBoxes in the group for some reason.

I have a Ribbon Group, then a separate RibbonComboBox for each combo box I need.  These also live inside of a grid.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have found that if I move the combobox to the top in the my XAML that the ComboBox I moved now works...but the other ones don't.  I am very confused by this.